# Always shown vertical and horizontal scroll indicator on a uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

i get html text and images from web services and load in webview. i need to add scroll indicator for vertical and horizontal scroll bar for view text and images. some of the large text and images user didn't notice full information. shown scroll indicators after finish loading webview

Answer (score 0):

Starting iOS 5.0 onwards, you can customize the scrolling behavior of UIWebView by accessing the 'scrollview' property to achieve the desired functionality:

Use the scroll view of the webview like this:

[webView.scrollView  setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
   [webView.scrollView  setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];

You can do one thing that ,use this

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView){

  ```
  [webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
  ```

  }

can set indicator color as -

webView.scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

Comment: its working...but display for few seconds..i need to display constatntly

Comment: is it displaying when you touch the screen??